# Peticiones en quasar framework modo ssr

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, express

¿La forma correcta de hacer un api rest con **quasar framework** modo ssr es en el archivo extension.js? Tengo este código pero cuando lo pruebo me sale **not found** (es un simple get):

```
module.exports.extendApp = function ({ app }) {
/*Extend the parts of the express app that youwant to use with development 
server too.Example: app.use(), app.get() etc*/ 
app.get("/aca", function(req, res) {  
       res.send("fdfsdfdsff") 
    })
}
```

Comment: Sin ssr te funciona?

Comment: No, porque sin ssr no tiene logica hacer un projecto en donde tambien ponga las peticiones al servidor, como se hace en nuxt js.